# Windows 10 Boot from USB stuck

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, laptop, bios

1. I've downloaded the **windows.iso** file and used rufus to burn a Windows image on the go to a portable USB Drive.
2. When it was finished, I unplugged and re-plugged the USB into my computer.
3. I used SHIFT+restart to open the recovery menu.
4. I selected the boot from the media option (I don't remember exactly what it was called)
5. Then I selected USB 3.0 partition 1.

At first it seemed to be booting normally. It showed the manufacturer screen (Asus) and the loading circle. However, it stayed on this screen for a while. Then it switched to a blank screen with the loading circle and text below it saying "getting ready". And it has stayed like this for forever. I tried to unplug the USB and the circle froze so I plugged it back in. I tried turning off the computer by pushing the power button but it won't do anything. I pressed every function key trying to open the bios. I tried physically closing my laptop and reopening it. After I pulled my laptop screen back up, the circle had frozen but if a pressed a key, it would resume loading.

Should I wait for it to run out of battery? I'm ok with factory resetting it but I don't know if I will be able to. The USB has a little led that blinks when the USB is being read/written to and it has been blinking the entire time with no pauses.

Comment: Use the [Windows USB/DVD download tool](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=56485) instead. Or if you are on linux, use [WoeUSB](https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB). AFAIK rufus writes the image as bit-by-bit copy, which is not sufficient for a windows ISO

Comment: Rufus should not have any problems with Windows ISOs, at least I've never had any.
What I would do is try a different USB stick.
The laptop can possibly be shut down by pressing the power button for something like 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by unplugging the USB and closing my laptop screen. After a while, I got the blue screen of death telling me the computer would restart. After it restarted, I could login to my normal windows with no problems.